# Submit a form to two servers

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, same-origin-policy, mechanicalturk

I want to be able to submit forms to two server. Here's why (if there is a better way of doing this, I'm all ears)

I have an iframe embedded on mechanical turk. The iframe has a form in it.

When a worker submits the form, I need to do two things:

I need to notify my local server so that I can take some actions right away.
I need to post the results to mturk so that the next job is displayed by turk.

If I do not do this, my server needs to poll turk for job completion, which is inefficient.

I have tried multiple schemes, but could not get them to work.

I have tried to use ajax to do one post locally, and one form submit, using code that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@task, :url => "http://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit", 
:remote => true, :method => "post", :authenticity_token => false) do |f| %>

....
```

and in my unobstrusive js file

```
$(form).post({url: "/notify",opt, function() {console.log("notify done")});
```

This results in a js error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit. Origin http://mytest.herokuapp.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have no control over the server, so I cannot fix this problem.

Any suggestions about the right way of doing this would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: Double-submission direct from the client is a ghastly approach. If two servers need the data then submit the form to a script on one (your local server), which performs its own processing and acts as a proxy for the other server - ie. makes an HTTP request of its own. With thought, you should be able to make a single response from the local server to the client, covering both aspects.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'd like to do - but the form submit has to be done from the client so that turk can forward to the next image. doing a POST from the server will not refresh the iframe, since the turk server has no way to update it

Comment: But surely the "next image" is just a url, which can be "piped through" in the response.

Comment: Moreover, by proxying all interaction with the turk server, you should be able to purge the iFrame in favour of a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided that I was thinking about it all wrong. I should not be trying to submit a form twice. Instead, I am submitting just to turk, and using their notification service using SQS (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/Concepts_NotificationsArticle.html) to get notified of the changes on the server

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to do with jQuery.  Essentially if you use the `.serialize()` method you can post the data to as many places as you want.

Assuming you have a form as such:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" value="abc123" />
    <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" value="def456" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You could have the following jQuery code that executes the POST

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.post("http://www.location1.com/somePlace/", data, function() { });
        $.post("http://www.location2.com/anotherPlace/", data, function() { });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - tried this out, no dice. I get the same error:XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit. Origin http://mytest.herokuapp.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Are you trying to load data back from the server?  An XMLHttpRequest would signal that you are trying to read data back from different domain than what you are serving the form from.